# Analytics API website content average session duration?

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I want to use the Analytics API and a PHP script that I run with a cron job once a day, to check the session duration of visitors at my content. This content sites are like this:

- domain.com/e/3747634
- domain.com/e/7843735

  ...

The purpose is, if I notice that the session duration is below 5 seconds, it is fake traffic and I can ban this page.

This is the relevant part of my code, there is the authentication part before, but this works and is not so important.

```
 //calulating start date
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));

//Adding Dimensions
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType');
// requesting the data
$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:xxxxxxxx", $date->format('Y-m-d'),  date("Y-m-d"), "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );


?><html>
<?php echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . " - ".date("Y-m-d"). "\n";?>
<table>
<tr>
<?php
//Printing column headers
foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){  
    print "<td>".$header['name']."</td>";   
}
?>
</tr>
<?php
//printing each row.
foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {    
    print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";  
}

//printing the total number of rows
?>
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>
</table>
</html>
<?php

?>
```

This displays:

```
2015-09-02 - 2015-09-03
ga:userType      ga:users ga:sessions
New Visitor        127108 127108
Returning Visitor  5849   13252
Rows Returned 2
```

**How can I get the average session duration of visitors on each of the content pages?** (For "today")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [dimensions and metric explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=user,session,traffic_sources,adwords,goal_conversions,platform_or_device,geo_network,system,social_activities,page_tracking,content_grouping,internal_search,site_speed,app_tracking,event_tracking,ecommerce,social_interactions,user_timings,exceptions,content_experiments,custom_variables_or_columns,time,doubleclick_campaign_manager,audience,adsense,channel_grouping,related_products) but i think what you want to do is make the following change to your code:

```
//Adding Dimensions
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:pagepath'); 
// requesting the data
$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:xxxxxxxx", $date->format('Y-m-d'),    date("Y-m-d"), "ga:avgSessionDuration", $params );
```

Also the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) is a good resource for experimenting with what various dimensions and metrics you want to request from the API.